# overlap and merge 2 wav files using c#

Tags: c#, audio, merge

I have two `.wav` files and I need to merge both the audio files in such a way that the last 2 seconds of the first file and the first 2 seconds of the second file are overlapped.

I have tried using naudio but it overlaps the full file from beginning to end.While I need to overlap only the 2 seconds where both files are merged.

How can i merge two audio files with 2 seconds of audio clip overlapped?

Comment: Have you tried inserting the required amount of silence at the start of one of the tracks first?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen No, do I need to add silence ? Because I don't want silence in the resultant audio file...

Comment: If you want to overlap the last 2 seconds of audio A with the first 2 seconds of audio B, I would create audio C, consisting of silence at the start, for N seconds where N is equal to the length of A minus 2 seconds, then add B to the end of C. Then you could simply overlay the two to get the results you want.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Great Idea... It sounds good... Thanks for that... I am going to try that and let you know...

Comment: Post your code, might help us to suggest solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have this, two pieces of audio, A and B, and you want to crossfade between the two when A ends and B starts, then you have this situation:

```
A |---------------------------------------|
B                                  |-------------------------|

                                   ^------^
                                  2 seconds
```

But, as you say, naudio overlays them from the start, doing this:

```
A |---------------------------------------|
B |-------------------------|
```

Then the solution is to insert enough silence before B to "move" it into place, unless you can coax naudio to do the move for you without it:

```
A |---------------------------------------|
B sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss|-------------------------|
```

If needed, you will need to append silence at the end of A as well, if naudio stops once one of the audio streams end:

```
A |---------------------------------------|sssssssssssssssssss
B sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss|-------------------------|
```